# What is the correct way to test django with APIReqFactory or mock?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I want to test with django, but they do not run and I do not understand, that I am wrong, the following error returns:
line 44, in test_put
res = self.view(req)
Ran 5 tests in 0.009s
FAILED (failures=2).
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
Expected view ActorViewSet to be called with a URL keyword argument named "pk". Fix your URL conf,
or set the `.lookup_field` attribute on the view correctly.

My testCase:

```
from rest_framework.test import APITestCase, APIRequestFactory

from .views import ActorViewSet

class TestActor(APITestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.factory = APIRequestFactory()
        self.view = ActorViewSet.as_view({'get': 'list',
                                      'get': 'retrieve',
                                      'post': 'create',
                                      'put': 'update',
                                      'delete': 'destroy'})
        self.url = '/actor/'

    def test_list(self):
        req = self.factory.get(self.url)
        res = self.view(req)
        self.assertEqual(res.status_code, 200,
                     'expected http code 200'
                     .format(res.status_code)
                     )

    def test_get_one(self):
        self.get_one_url = '/actor/1'
        req = self.factory.get(self.get_one_url, format='json')
        res = self.view(req)
        self.assertEqual(res.status_code, 200,
                     'expected http code 200'
                     .format(res.status_code)
                     )

    def test_create(self):
        data = {'movie_title': 'type', 'name': 'TCY', 'awards': 5}
        req = self.factory.post(self.url, data, format='json')
        res = self.view(req)
        self.assertEqual(res.status_code, 201,
                     'exepted created 201'
                     .format(res.status_code)
                     )

    def test_put(self):
        self.get_one_url = '/actor/1'
        data = {'movie_title': 'type', 'name': 'TCY', 'awards': 3}
        req = self.factory.put(self.get_one_url, data, format='json')
        res = self.view(req)
        self.assertEqual(res.status_code, 204,
                     'expected http code 204'
                     .format(res.status_code)
                     )

    def test_destroy(self):
        self.get_one_url = '/actor/1'
        data = {'movie_title': 'type', 'name': 'TCY', 'awards': 3}
        req = self.factory.delete(self.get_one_url, data, format='json')
        res = self.view(req)
        self.assertEqual(res.status_code, 204,
                     'expected http code 204'
                     .format(res.status_code)
                     )
```

grateful for your comments.

trace:

```
(venv) C:\Users\Admin\PycharmProjects\apiTime>manage.py test
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
.F..F
======================================================================
FAIL: test_del (api.tests.TestActor)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Admin\PycharmProjects\apiTime\api\tests.py", line 54, in test_del
    res = self.view(req)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\PycharmProjects\apiTime\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\PycharmProjects\apiTime\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\viewsets.py", line 114, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\PycharmProjects\apiTime\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 505, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\PycharmProjects\apiTime\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 465, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\PycharmProjects\apiTime\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 476, in raise_uncaught_exception
    raise exc
  File "C:\Users\Admin\PycharmProjects\apiTime\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 502, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\PycharmProjects\apiTime\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\mixins.py", line 90, in destroy
    instance = self.get_object()
  File "C:\Users\Admin\PycharmProjects\apiTime\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\generics.py", line 88, in get_object
    assert lookup_url_kwarg in self.kwargs, (
AssertionError: Expected view ActorViewSet to be called with a URL keyword argument named "pk". Fix your URL conf, or set the `.lookup_field` attribute on the view correctly.

======================================================================
FAIL: test_put (api.tests.TestActor)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Admin\PycharmProjects\apiTime\api\tests.py", line 44, in test_put
    res = self.view(req)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\PycharmProjects\apiTime\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\PycharmProjects\apiTime\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\viewsets.py", line 114, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\PycharmProjects\apiTime\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 505, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\PycharmProjects\apiTime\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 465, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\PycharmProjects\apiTime\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 476, in raise_uncaught_exception
    raise exc
  File "C:\Users\Admin\PycharmProjects\apiTime\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 502, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\PycharmProjects\apiTime\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\mixins.py", line 65, in update
    instance = self.get_object()
  File "C:\Users\Admin\PycharmProjects\apiTime\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\generics.py", line 88, in get_object
    assert lookup_url_kwarg in self.kwargs, (
AssertionError: Expected view ActorViewSet to be called with a URL keyword argument named "pk". Fix your URL conf, or set the `.lookup_field` attribute on the view correctly.

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 5 tests in 0.009s

FAILED (failures=2)
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
```

Comment: Can you post traceback for the exception?

Comment: Do your URLs need to have a trailing slash? `'/actor/1/'`

Comment: @IainShelvington nah, i tried it!

Comment: Do you have a full traceback in your log output? Which line is causing the error?

Comment: ready! <3 hehehe @IainShelvington

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a bit late, but since this was my first google hit I want to give the solution for others may having the same issue.

```
def test_put(self):
    self.get_one_url = '/actor/'
    data = {'movie_title': 'type', 'name': 'TCY', 'awards': 3}
    req = self.factory.put(self.get_one_url, data, format='json')
    res = self.view(req, pk=1)
    self.assertEqual(
        res.status_code, 204,
        'expected http code 204'.format(
            res.status_code
         ))
```

Hope that saves someone some time